# Copy bootable linux compact flash to SD card

Tags: linux, boot, bootable-media

I have a bootable Linux compact flash card and want to copy it to an SD card.  What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Boot up a copy of Linux that isn't your CF Linux. Open a terminal emulator.
2. Run `fdisk -l` and find your CF card and SD card (they may have identifiable sizes or labels). I'll assume that they're `/dev/sde` and `/dev/sdf`.
3. Run `dd if=/dev/sde of=/dev/sdf`.

And don't forget to backup your hard drive. Every time someone wipes their hard drive from a mistype, another fairie dies.

If the extreme power of [dd](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) is too much to handle, you may find [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) a bit more manageable.

Comment: Not fairies but bogons die - once the ones left can be overpowered by cluons, enlightenment has been achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
dd if=/dev/CF of=/dev/SD
```

But seriously, to be able to meaningfully answer your question we need to know more about

- relative sizes of the two devices
- how the CF card is partitioned, if indeed it is
- what bootloader you're using

Comment: Both the CompactFlash and SD card are 4GBs.  The CompactFlash appears to have 3.5GB partition that I can see in my Ubuntu box.  The bootloader is Ubuntu.  I tried a dd on these and it doesn't seem to copy the part with the bootable system files as it won't boot when I use the SD card.  I guess a dd won't copy the partition I would have partition the SD card and then run the dd?

Comment: @user208861, edit your question to add those details, and also the commands you've tried and what appeared to happen.

Comment: `dd` does what it's told, so if you specify `if=` and `of=` as the whole-device files for their corresponding devices, then it *will* copy the bootcode. See digitxp's answer.